# Query Postgres 9.3 JSON to check if array contains a string?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

A line in my JSON column looks something like this:

```
{"general": {
        "somekey": "somevalue", 
        "tags": ["first_tag", "second_tag", "third_tag"]}}
```

And I need to return lines with tags list that contains certain tag (e.g. "first_tag"). Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the table is called `t` and the column is called `x`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE exists(
  SELECT 1
  FROM json_array_elements(x#>'{general,tags}')
  WHERE array_to_json(array[value])->>0='first_tag'
);
```

This does not use `jsonb` or other newer stuff so it should work on 9.3. See also [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6e09b/10).

The idea is to use the `json_array_elements` function, which converts a json array into a sql table. That table has a single column called `value` of type `json`.

In this case, we use `json_array_elements` in a subquery to iterate through the list of all tags. One complication is that `value` (which here represents a tag) is of type `json`, so we have to convert it to a text. Unfortunately, `postgresql` doesn't have a function to do that directly, so we have to convert it into a single element array and then extract that single element as text. Then we can compare that text with the tag we are look for (`first_tag` in the above example). The result of this column is not significant, we are only interested in whether it is empty or not.

Comment: When I run the inner query from your example, i get the list of tags from all records. However when I run the full query, I get 0 lines.

Comment: @BanzaiTokyo I tweak the string test, it should now work.

Comment: I have no idea how it works but it does!! Thank you so much! I would appreciate it if you could share a link where I could read more about querying json in Postgres 9.3 especially for terms like "contains". Because the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) doesn't explain much.

Comment: @BanzaiTokyo I have no further reference to give you, I expanded it a little bit my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: could you just explain what the **value** in this query is and why are we checking only the first element ( ->>0) of the ARRAY? Also it seems strange to me that the inner query doesn't reference the table. Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: I updated the answer with some more info. The inner query does reference the table through the column `x`.

Comment: Thank you very much! now I see what `array_to_json(array[value])->>0` is doing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_json_array_contains(a_json json, a_e anyelement)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN to_json(a_e)::TEXT IN (SELECT value::TEXT FROM json_array_elements(a_json) e);
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
;

SELECT * FROM t WHERE fn_json_array_contains(x#>'{general,tags}', 'first_tag');
```